# drawing two spline series with different number of values

Tags: javascript, highcharts, line

i have to draw two different spline series. i got  the values of the first line from a webservice, instead the second one is composed by two only values that means that is a straight line.
the code is the following

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '€ ' + this.value;
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: seriesMesi
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'scenario sfavorevole',
            color: '#FF3300',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [0, 12175],
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'none',
                lineColor: null
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Valori del piano',
            color: 'blue',
            type: 'spline',
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'none',
                lineColor: null
            }
        }]
};

options.series[1].data = seriesValoriPiano;
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

I can't represent the straight line: it has to occupy the whole x axis that means between the first and the last x values, but in my case it occupies only the range between the first and the second x values.
How can i do to represent a straight line that occupies all the x values?

thank you very much

Comment: What is the value of `seriesMesi`?

Comment: If you put an example on jsFiddle it will help people to see the problem. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get data from webservice by $.ajax();

```
$.get(url,function(data){

var options = {
series:[{
    //your hardcoded data
  },{
    data:data //data from ajax
  }]
}

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


});
```

Comment: The data of the straight line are static, i have two points x:0, y: 0 and x: n, y: m i can't represent it! the second point seems to assume the x like the second in the category serie